# Lightmap resolution

Tags: aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

I'm unable to get the high-res light bake to show in Aframe - only the low-res. Is the archilogic high-res lightmap bake compatible with Aframe?

https://appcreator.3d.io/iQrBlG?m=nv

The 3D.io renderer seems much more noisier than the Archilogic viewer.
[image: Amplified noise in aframe]

Comment: They load for me. Are you sure they don't load? Unlike the low-res, the high-res textures are currently in the "dds" format, which don't show up under "images" in the browser network debugger.

Comment: I see the high-res & low-res lightmaps load in the debugger (lm_0__1.hi-res.gz.dds & lm_0__1.lo-res.jpg), however the noise seems a lot more amplified in 3D.io renderer compared to Archilogic. I've updated this with an image for reference.

Comment: I guess I'd like to confirm the high-res image overrides the low-res once it's loaded - is it simply a matter of adjusting the lightmap intensity to reduce noise?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, it's a known problem that it looks worse in the aframe renderer, so yes, I'm sure it loads the high-res (otherwise the resolution would be lower), and yes, it's best keeping the intensity low enough so it doesn't stand out as much.